# Video encoding with AV1 - FFmpeg

Tags: video, encoding, command-line, ffmpeg

I was trying to encode a raw video with AV1.

I used: `ffmpeg -i netflixboxing720p.y4m -c:v libaom-av1 -b:v 500k -strict experimental netflix720p500AV1.mp4`

I took 2 hours and when I open the created video I get nothing. I would play the Video.
Do I need an other command line?

```
    ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2-with-options_2 --enable-shared --cc=clang --host-cflags=-fno-stack-check --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-htmlpages --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, yuv4mpegpipe, from 'netflixboxing720p.y4m':
  Duration: 00:00:04.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 497667 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (Y3[11][10] / 0xA0B3359), yuv420p10le(progressive), 720x480, SAR 512:405 DAR 256:135, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> av1 (libaom-av1))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libaom-av1 @ 0x7f8e3180e200] 1.0.0
Output #0, mp4, to 'netflix720p500AV1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: av1 (libaom-av1) (av01 / 0x31307661), yuv420p10le, 720x480 [SAR 512:405 DAR 256:135], q=-1--1, 500 kb/s, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libaom-av1
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=   22 fps=0.5 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.05 bitrate=   7.0kbits/frame=   23 fps=0.4 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.06 bitrate=   5.3kbits/frame=   24 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=   4.2kbits/frame=   25 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.10 bitrate=   3.5kbits/frame=   26 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.11 bitrate=   3.0kbits/frame=   27 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.13 bitrate=   2.6kbits/frame=   28 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.15 bitrate=   2.3kbits/frame=   29 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.16 bitrate=   2.1kbits/frame=   30 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.18 bitrate=   1.9kbits/frame=   31 fps=0.2 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=   1.8kbits/frame=   32 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.21 bitrate=   1.6kbits/frame=   33 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.23 bitrate=   1.5kbits/frame=   34 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.25 bitrate=   1.4kbits/frame=   35 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.26 bitrate=   1.3kbits/frame=   36 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.28 bitrate=   1.2kbits/frame=   37 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.30 bitrate=   1.2kbits/frame=   38 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.31 bitrate=   1.1kbits/frame=   39 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.33 bitrate=   1.1kbits/frame=   40 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.35 bitrate=   1.0kbits/frame=   41 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=   1.0kbits/frame=   42 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.38 bitrate=   0.9kbits/frame=   43 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.40 bitrate=   0.9kbits/frame=   44 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.41 bitrate=   0.8kbits/frame=   45 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.43 bitrate=   0.8kbits/frame=   46 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.45 bitrate=   0.8kbits/frame=   47 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=   0.8kbits/frame=   48 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.48 bitrate=   0.7kbits/frame=   49 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.50 bitrate=   0.7kbits/frame=   50 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.51 bitrate=   0.7kbits/frame=   51 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.53 bitrate=   0.7kbits/frame=   52 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.55 bitrate=   0.6kbits/frame=   53 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.56 bitrate=   0.6kbits/frame=   54 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.58 bitrate=   0.6kbits/frame=   55 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.60 bitrate=   0.6kbits/frame=   56 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.61 bitrate=   0.6kbits/frame=   57 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.63 bitrate=   0.6kbits/frame=   58 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.65 bitrate=   0.5kbits/frame=   59 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.66 bitrate=   0.5kbits/frame=   60 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.68 bitrate=   0.5kbits/frame=   61 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.70 bitrate=   0.5kbits/frame=   62 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.71 bitrate=   0.5kbits/frame=   63 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.73 bitrate=   0.5kbits/frame=   64 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.75 bitrate=   0.5kbits/frame=   65 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.76 bitrate=   0.5kbits/frame=   66 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.78 bitrate=   0.4kbits/frame=   67 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.80 bitrate=   0.4kbits/frame=   68 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.81 bitrate=   0.4kbits/frame=   69 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.83 bitrate=   0.4kbits/frame=   70 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.85 bitrate=   0.4kbits/frame=   71 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.86 bitrate=   0.4kbits/frame=   72 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.88 bitrate=   0.4kbits/frame=   73 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.90 bitrate=   0.4kbits/frame=   74 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.91 bitrate=   0.4kbits/frame=   75 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB tframe=   83 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=    frame=   84 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.08 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   85 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.10 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   86 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.11 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   87 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.13 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   88 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.15 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   89 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.16 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   90 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.18 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   91 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.20 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   92 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.21 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   93 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.23 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   94 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.25 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   95 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.26 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   96 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.28 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   97 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.30 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   98 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.31 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=   99 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.33 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=  100 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.35 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=  101 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.36 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=  102 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.38 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=  103 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.40 bitrate=   0.3kbits/frame=  104 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.41 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  105 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.43 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  106 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.45 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  107 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.46 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  108 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.48 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  109 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.50 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  110 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.51 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  111 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.53 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  112 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.55 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  113 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.56 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  114 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.58 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  115 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.60 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  116 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.61 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  117 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.63 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  118 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.65 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  119 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.66 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  120 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.68 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  121 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.70 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  122 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.71 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  123 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.73 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  124 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.75 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  125 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.76 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  126 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.78 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  127 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.80 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  128 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.81 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  129 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.83 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  130 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.85 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  131 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.86 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  132 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.88 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  133 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.90 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  134 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.91 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  135 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.93 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  136 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.95 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  137 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.96 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  138 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.98 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  139 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  140 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.01 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  141 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.03 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  142 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.05 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  143 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.06 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  144 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.08 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  145 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.10 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  146 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.11 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  147 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.13 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  148 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.15 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  149 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.16 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  150 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.18 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  151 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.20 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  152 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.21 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  153 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.23 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  154 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.25 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  155 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.26 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  156 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.28 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  157 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.30 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  158 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.31 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  159 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.33 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  160 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.35 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  161 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.36 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  162 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.38 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  163 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.40 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  164 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.41 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  165 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.43 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  166 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.45 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  167 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.46 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  168 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.48 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  169 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.50 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  170 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.51 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  171 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.53 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  172 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.55 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  173 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.56 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  174 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.58 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  175 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.60 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  176 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.61 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  177 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.63 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  178 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.65 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  179 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  180 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.68 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  181 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.70 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  182 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.71 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  183 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.73 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  184 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.75 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  185 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.76 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  186 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.78 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  187 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.80 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  188 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.81 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  189 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.83 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  190 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.85 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  191 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.86 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  192 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.88 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  193 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.90 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  194 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.91 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  195 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.93 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  196 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.95 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  197 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.96 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  198 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.98 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  199 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  200 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.01 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  201 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.03 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  202 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.05 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  203 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.06 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  204 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.08 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  205 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.10 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  206 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.11 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  207 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.13 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  208 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.15 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  209 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.16 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  210 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.18 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  211 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.20 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  212 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.21 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  213 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.23 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  214 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.25 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  215 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.26 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  216 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.28 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  217 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.30 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  218 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.31 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  219 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.33 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  220 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.35 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  221 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.36 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  222 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.38 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  223 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.40 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  224 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.41 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  225 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.43 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  226 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.45 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  227 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.46 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  228 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.48 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  229 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.50 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  230 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.51 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  231 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.53 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  232 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.55 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  233 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.56 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  234 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.58 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  235 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.60 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  236 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.61 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  237 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.63 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  238 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.65 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  239 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.66 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  240 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.68 bitrate= 569.4kbits/frame=  241 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.70 bitrate= 566.9kbits/frame=  242 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.71 bitrate= 564.3kbits/frame=  243 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.73 bitrate= 561.8kbits/frame=  244 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.75 bitrate= 559.3kbits/frame=  245 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.76 bitrate= 556.8kbits/frame=  246 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.78 bitrate= 554.4kbits/frame=  247 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.80 bitrate= 552.0kbits/frame=  248 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.81 bitrate= 549.6kbits/frame=  249 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.83 bitrate= 547.2kbits/frame=  250 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.85 bitrate= 544.8kbits/frame=  251 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.86 bitrate= 542.4kbits/frame=  252 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.88 bitrate= 540.1kbits/frame=  253 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.90 bitrate= 537.8kbits/frame=  254 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.91 bitrate= 535.5kbits/frame=  254 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.91 bitrate= 535.5kbits/frame=  254 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=     290kB time=00:00:04.21 bitrate= 563.8kbits/s speed=0.000602x    
video:289kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.447550%
```

Comment: How did you play the file? Have you tried ffplay?

Comment: I played with Elmedia player. I did encode videos with vp9 and Hevc. the playing the file wasn't a problem. Could it be that i have to install something before the encoding?

Comment: Elmedia probably doest support AV1 (Dont confuse AV1 with AVI)

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i netflixboxing720p.y4m -c:v libaom-av1 -b:v 500k -strict experimental -pix_fmt yuv420p netflix720p500AV1.mp4
```

Try this one, it may get work. Sometimes when I convert videos as well the even with common formats like mp4 it doesn't play on my phone, but when I convert it with yuv420 it works.